# How to fill a cell in multiple worksheet based on another group of data?

Tags: excel, vba

On the master sheet, Column A have some of **data A** e.g

A1=Tools 1, A2=Tools 2, A3=Tools 3, ..., A50=Tools 50

There will be 50 sheets, which sheet 1 cell B7=Tools 1, sheet 2 cell B7=Tools 2.

Is there any solution which it will **automatically fill cell B7** with **data A** until **sheet 50**?

PS: Since I need to manually duplicate the template sheets to 50 sheet, appreciate if it can automatically create new sheet with cell B7 automatically filled up with **data A.**

Comment: What I've explored is it is reversed to Dynamically Refer to Worksheet Kutools function. I've stuck as there is no guide available in the internet. You may refer to this link and read step 4. https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2597-excel-autofill-same-cell-different-sheet.html

Comment: If I were you, the first thing I think about is the the process. For example : I macro recording when I manually add a new sheet and then rename it. After I see the resulted code, then the next thing I think is that how do I make the code to do 50 times creating a new sheet with different name (as column A in the master sheet has 50 data : tools 1 to tools 50). (continue)

Comment: So I will look in the internet on how to loop the recorded code based on how many data and value in column A of the master sheet... how to make a dynamic variable for each created sheet's name and then how to fill cell B7 of each created sheet with each looped cell value in column A master sheet.

Comment: I've solved the problem by using Kutools, but indirect solution. Should I just mark close or just share the solution?